# How to subtract a view in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview

For example I have a `view`, which is **320 * 320**, black color, and alpha channel is 0.5.
I would like to open a `view` with position **100*100** , and width and height as **50*50**. That's allow me to not apply the, black color,  alpha channel 0.5 is that area.
How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: You'd have to override the draw rect method in the view and draw the black (50%) colour and mask the area you don't want to colour in. You can't subtract a view in this way.

Comment: Do you want another view at (100, 100) and having the same color as the other view?

Comment: It sounds like he wants a "window" through the black view. i.e. all black (50%) apart from a 100x100 window.

Answer (score -1):

The easier way of doing something like this would be to just use something like Photoshop to create the 320x320 image, and then remove the 50x50 window wherever you wan it. Make sure you save it as a `png`, and you will be good to go. No point in making things too complicated. Now if this image needs to change, it is more complicated, but that was not described in the problem.